# How to render conditionally depending on which button is clicked?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to ReactJS and I want to have a conditional rendering like the code below

I read the [doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) but I was a bit confused.

Do I have to handle true/false for each buttons similar to the doc?

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Render "ABC"/"DEF"/"XYZ" depends on which button is clicked</h1>
        <Button>ABC</Button>
        <Button>DEF</Button>
        <Button>XYZ</Button>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a map (an object in JS) with key-boolean pair if you want to control multiple button states. Like

```
const [buttonStates, setButtonStates] = useState({
    "ABC": false,
    "DEF": true,
    "XYZ": true,
});
```

Then

```
{buttonStates["ABC"] && <>"ABC"</>}
{buttonStates["DEF"] && <>"DEF"</>}
{buttonStates["XYZ"] && <>"XYZ"</>}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can control this situation with simply one state.
For Example :

```
const [whicheBtn, setWicheBtn] = useState("btnA")
```

and in your component, you should check for the value of the `whicheBtn` state.

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Render "ABC"/"DEF"/"XYZ" depends on which button is clicked</h1>
        {whicheBtn == "ABC" &&  <Button>ABC</Button> }
         {whicheBtn == "DEF" && <Button>DEF</Button>}
         {whicheBtn == "XYZ" && <Button>XYZ</Button> }
      </div>
    )
  }
```